# UV unwrapping: Blender always selects an edge ring as a "seam"

Tags: uv

So I have the following issue:

I'm trying to unwrap the top of this platform. 
I choose some vertical seams on the sides (screenshot), with the objective that the unwrapped model will look like it was flattened from above.

[image: problem]

The problem is, Blender always seems to choose one entire edge ring as a seam. I tried "Clear Seam" and "Clear Edge", with no results. This is causing some vertices split, and is giving me some problems when painting the texture.

Is there a way to tell Blender NOT to cut through a specific edge when unwrapping?

[image: Expected result]

Hopefully you guys can help me achieve my expected result :)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you try to select all and Remove Doubles? So you can be sure your geometry is all connected.

Comment: Are you the default Unwrap? Smart Unwrap?

Comment: @JanKadeřábek  I didn't! Now that you mention it, I think this might do the trick. When modelling this I split the platform top into two separate objects and later I rejoined them, perhaps I have duplicates.
I'll reply if it worked later today when I get home.

I just used the default unwrap with 4 seams (2 of them are shown in the first picture, the other 2 are on the back side)

Comment: Removing Doubles did the trick! Many thanks @JanKadeřábek!

Comment: I am happy it helped! I have added my tip as an answer, you can accept it so others can quickly see the solution. Thanks and happy Blending :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is often happening when the mesh of your model is not all connected.

To merge vertices placed in the same position:

1. Go into *Edit Mode* <kbd>Tab</kbd>
2. Select all <kbd>A</kbd>
3. Open *Specials* menu <kbd>W</kbd>, select *Remove Doubles*
   [image]
4. Unwrap the model again